# Out parameters with RhinoMocks

Tags: rhino-mocks

I'm obviously confused - this is a task I've accomplished with several other frameworks we're considering (NMock, Moq, FakeItEasy).  I have a function call I'd like to stub.  The function call has an out parameter (an object).

The function call is in a use case that is called multiple times within the code.  The calling code hands in parameters, including a NULL object for the out parameter.  I'd like to set up an expected OUT parameter, based on the other parameters provided.

How can I specify an expected INBOUND out parameter of NULL, **and** an expected OUTBOUND out parameter of an object populated the way I expect it?  I've tried it six ways to Sunday, and so far haven't been able to get anything back but NULL for my OUTBOUND out parameter.

Answer (score 22):

From http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#OutandRefarguments:

> Ref and out arguments are special, because you also have to make the
>   compiler happy. The keywords ref and out are mandantory, and you need
>   a field as argument. Arg won't let you down:
>
> ```
> User user;
> if (stubUserRepository.TryGetValue("Ayende", out user))
> {
>   //...
> }
> stubUserRepository.Stub(x =>
>   x.TryGetValue(
>     Arg.Is("Ayende"), 
>     out Arg<User>.Out(new User()).Dummy))
>   .Return(true);
> ```
>
> out is mandantory for the compiler. Arg.Out(new User()) is the
>   important part for us, it specifies that the out argument should
>   return new User(). Dummy is just a field of the specified type User,
>   to make the compiler happy.

Comment: The link now gets a 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 6):

In case using repository to generate Mock/Stub

```
checkUser = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICheckUser>
```

You can setup expectation with out parameter

```
checkUser
.Expect(c => c.TryGetValue(Arg.Is("Ayende"), out Arg<User>.Out(new User()).Dummy)
.Return(true)
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution is cleaner and works fine with Rhino Mocks 3.6:

```
myStub.Stub(x => x.TryGet("Key", out myValue))
      .OutRef("value for the out param")
      .Return(true);
```

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me. It wouldn't recognize the `out Arg<User>.Out` syntax. +1

Comment: I would also add that as of C# 7.0, you can use an underscore as a discard for the `out` variable, simplifying it further to `x.TryGet("Key", out _)` (which also saves you from having to declare `myValue` elsewhere).